# Differential and single ended crosstalk and clearance

Tags: impedance, transmission-line, single-ended, differential-amplifier

I know that there can be crosstalk between differential pairs (and you need at least a few lengths equal to the diff pair between diff pairs, usually 3 or more diff pair widths).

What is the recommendation for clearance between a diff pair and a single ended trace?

Comment: How much isolation is required?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of single ended (SE) signal.  In general, on average, we use spacings of 10 mil.

More if the SE signal is critical like a clock or a reset.  A bit less if the signal is considered non-critical like an address line.

At the end of the routing phase, we import the routing and signal info into an SI tool to calculate the expected cross talk.  Design rules flag any violations that the designer can then examine and see if any further remediation is needed.

Note that if the diff pair and the SE signal are on the same layer, then the SE  signal and one of the diff pair signals will edge couple to each other.  This is more like a SE to SE coupling than a diff pair to SE coupling.

Comment: Have you ever ran your designs through SI tools?

Comment: Yes.  That's what I was trying to say in the last paragraph.